# What is the use of uploading certificates in server in wso2-emm 2.2.0

Tags: wso2-iot

I am using  Wso2-emm 2.2.0 in my ubuntu machine and currently I am just exploring the web console for my future project. While going  through Configuration Management > Certificate Configurations, I am not able to find the use of uploading certificates (in .pem format) in the server.
If any such use is there please tell me because my project needs installation of X.509 digital certificates on android, ios and windows device for achieving BYOD implementation.

Thanks in advance and help is appreciated
gaurav sharma

Answer (score 0):

This is used to enroll devices using mutual SLL.

This feature is only allowed for android devices only.